# Pass dynamic ID to router_link - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to pass a dynamic ID to the router_link but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

This is what I'm currently trying:

```
<router-link to="/leagues/{{props.item.id}}">League</router_link>
```

That `props.item.id` equals `10` but this syntax isn't correct. I'm also referencing the documentation but I can't seem to find a straightforward answer for this. Any help would be great.

Comment: `:to="'/leagues/' + props.item.id"`. You can't use interpolation in attributes in Vue 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so passing a dynamic ID to vue-router should look like this:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'League', params: {id: props.item.id}}">League</router_link>
```

Comment: I expected to see something like this: `:to=" '/leagues/' + {{props.item.id}}"` but I guess this one works better. :P

Comment: does this solution reflects on url?

Comment: just what i needed thnks